# charging speed from USB QC3.0 to USB-C PD

Tags: usb, charging, usb-device, usb-c, usb-pd

I am trying to find this information online for a while but I cannot find any precise info, thus Q on this community seems appropriate.

I would like to know if a [device](https://www.xtorm.eu/en/power-banks/xtorm-60w-power-bank-voyager-26-000/) having USB PD charging port (capable to charge with 60W) will be able to use USB QC3.0 charging speed capabilities well?

Maybe it is manufacture specific matter and I should not expect to be any rule here? Then I just need to write to manufacturer and ask it is in cas of that specific device.

Thank you

Comment: *USB QC3.0 charging speeds* What does that mean? Do you mean "charging with the same amount of power as specified in QC3.0" ? or do you mean: "Quick charging according the QC3.0 standard"?

Comment: Also: "charging speed" is irrelevant, any USB quick/fast charging standard specifies a certain amount of **power** that can be used for charging. I can still charge a battery slowly using 1 W of power when there is 60 W available (this actually happens when the battery is almost empty and almost full). A device might only up to 30 W of the 60 W available. Also "speed" depends on the battery capacity, charging a 2 Ah battery at 60 W will take half the time as charging a 4 Ah battery at 60 W. Does that mean the charging speed is higher in case of the 2 Ah battery? Both are charged with 60 W.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thank you for your comment. I must admit that your Q in first comment confuses me. I would expect "as specific in QC3.0" to be exactly what the "QC3.0 standard" is. My goal is to know if QC3.0 source can be fully (or close to) utilized by USB PD device.

Comment: USB-C uses PD and only PD. Any other proprietary charging mode/signature will be out of specifications. So a device With Type-C PD won't be using any QC capabilities.

Comment: @Ale..chenski sounds like a good an simple answer to my question! Please post

Comment: Actually, it is not quite simple. My comment assumes adherence to current specification. Initial editions of Type-C connector did allow the use of alternative/proprietary charging modes.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I encourage you to put your comments into an answer as they deserve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per USB Type-C Specifications, rev.1.3 (2017), p.188:

**4.8.1 DFP as a Power Source**

Sources (e.g. battery chargers, hub downstream ports and hosts) may all be used for battery
charging. When a charger is implemented with a USB Type-C receptacle or a USB Type-C
captive cable, it shall follow all the applicable requirements.

- If a Source is capable of supplying a voltage greater than default
  VBUS, it shall fully conform to the USB-PD specification, and shall
  negotiate its power contracts **using only USB-PD**.

and

**4.8.2 Non-USB Charging Methods**

A product (Source and/or Sink) with a USB Type-C connector shall only employ signaling methods defined in USB specifications to negotiate power over its USB Type-C connector(s).

So, implementation of any other proprietary charging mode/signature will be out of specifications.

However, earlier editions of Type-C connector specs (up to rev. 1.2) did allow the use of alternative/proprietary charging modes; not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's difficult to tell whether you're interested in charging the power bank or charging another device using the powerbank.

Anyway,in order to use USB Power Delivery (USB-PD) or use QuickCharge (QC), both the power source and the power sink must support the same standard (either USB-PD or QC), the same version of the standard and the same voltages. Otherwise, they fall back to standard USB using 5V.

The xtorm web site specifies the capabilities:

**Output**

- 1x USB-C PD 60W
- 1x USB-C 15W (5V/3A)
- 2x USB Quick Charge 3.0 18W

**Input**

- USB-C PD 60W

So the power bank can provide power to devices using both the USB-C and QC standard. Using QC, it's limited to 18W. Using USB-PD, it can provide up to 60W if the sink device can also handle 60W (probably at 20V).

However, the power bank can only be charged using USB-PD. It cannot be charged using QC. It's probably possible to charge it using 5V, which often goes up to 2A. So you have a charging power of 10W. If you charge the power bank that way, expect it to take 6x longer than using USB-PD at 60W.

**Update**

According to your comment, you want to charge the power bank using a solar panel. To charge it at the maximum speed, your solar panel would need to support USB PD with 60W, i.e. it needs to talk the USB-PD protocol and it would need to support the power mode with a voltage of 20V and a current of at least 3A.

Quick Charge (QC) won't help as your power bank does not support this protocol on the input.

Charging might also work using standard USB with 5V. It's hard to predict what current would be used in this mode, probably 1A, possibly 2A. It would result in a charging power of 5W (5V x 1A) or possibly 10W (5V x 2A).  As the charging speed is approximately linear to the charging power, charging would take 12x or 6x longer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Power bank is device being charged, and device that is charging is going to be solar panel. I am not sure if it make sense to look for solar panels having QC3.0 output, thus my question.

Comment: do you mind updating your answer knowing now which device is being charged and which is charging?

Comment: @jangorecki See my update.